# Jquery with area tag and popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JS file I use Jquery to show a popup on the map. However, if the popup does not have a picture then, when you hover over it, the top margin becomes as if the popup has image. Here is my screenshot [I direct on area without picture](http://take.ms/oRMCg) and after twice direction script work fine. Why is that? Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/n8m6jav6/2/). Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var plashka = $('.plashka');
var img  = $('.plashka img');
var area = $('area');
plashka.hide();
area.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    $('#plashka_name').html('<strong>Название: </strong>' + $(this).data('name'));
    $('#plashka_category').html('<strong>Категория: </strong>' + $(this).data('type'));
    if($(this).data('link')) {
        $('.plashka a').attr({"href":$(this).data('link')}).html('Узнать подробнее');
    } else {
        $('.plashka a').html('');
    }
    if($(this).data('image')) {
        img.attr({'src':$(this).data('image')});
        plashka.show();
    } else {
    img.attr({'src':''});
    }
    setTimeout(function(){plashka.show();},150);
    var pw = plashka .outerWidth(true);
    var ph = plashka .outerHeight(true);
    var coords = $(this).attr('coords').split(',');
    var left = parseInt(coords[0])-pw/1.08;
    var top = parseInt(coords[1])-ph/1.08;
    plashka.css({'left': left, 'top':top}); 
});

area.on('mouseout', function (e) {
      plashka.hide();
});
plashka.on('mouseover', function(e){
   plashka.show();
});
$('.map_floor').on('mouseout', function(){
    plashka.hide();
});
});
```

Comment: You might want to change the language of your screenshots and add css in your fiddle.

Comment: And there is a different way that you can post links in your question. You can try clicking on the link symbol.

Comment: I add the link with a part of my code. here a screenshot after twice direction [twice direction](http://take.ms/kjRPn)

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using `:hover`?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="example">
        <div class="plashka">
            <strong>Название: </strong>
        </div>
        test</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    padding:100px;
}

.example {
    background:blue;
}

.plashka {
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    margin-left:-60px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    display:none;    
}
.example:hover .plashka{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vbb7v2wr/

Comment: Becouse content in div.plaska changes depends on area. Sorry, I foreign add style. [there with css and image](http://jsfiddle.net/n8m6jav6/14/). As can you see margin changes depends on hover area.

Comment: You could create a different plashkha for each location?